# Can I use model classes inside IValueConverter?

Tags: c#, mvvm

For example:

```
using Person; // <-- resides inside Model layer!!!! is *that* allowed???

public class PersonNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((Person)value).Name;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I wonder if there isn't any MVVM rule I violate here.

Comment: Using this in a converter is fine, no rules are being violated. Can you show how you're using this converter?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I am actually using IMultiValueConverter which gets a converting unit (meters/km/feet) and a value (in meters). The unit resides in the Model and determines how to present (for the view) all values related to range (i.e from one point to another). For how I am using that, is by simple MultiBinding for the specified **value** and the **converting unit** (simple enum).